# Is it possible to only run one application as non-retina whereas everything else is retina?

Tags: display

I have a Macbook Pro Retina 15" (Mid 2014). For whatever reason I noticed that one application (Netbeans) is a lot faster (the interface) when it runs in a non-retina screen (noticed this when I connected a second non-retina display).

I don't really like using a second display. And I also really like the retina graphics. Is it possible to only run **one** application (Netbeans) as non-retina whereas everything else is retina?

OSX Yosemite 10.10.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select Netbeans in Finder, right click and press "Get Info" (or press <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> on the keyboard). In the window that pops up, check "Open in Low Resolution".

Comment: Well, it definitely answers the question so I marked this answer. However, I am under the impression that Netbeans is still slow in my retina monitor compared to my non-retina one. Weird.

Comment: For future reference: the reason Netbeans is slow on Mac is a particular bug with it. Netbeans 8.0.2 should fix it.